# Trying to install ADB on Ubuntu, permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions

When I tried to install ADB through the terminal on Ubuntu, it told me "permission denied":

```
~/android-sdks/tools/ $ ./android
bash: ./android: Permission denied
~/android-sdks/platform-tools/ $ ./adb devices
bash: ./adb: Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `android` file (and others) are executable.

If you run `chmod +x android`, that should set the executable permission, which would allow you to run the binary.

To do this for all files in `tools` or `platform tools`, simply run:

```
chmod +x ~/android-sdks/tools/*
chmod +x ~/android-sdks/platform-tools/*
```

Answer (score 2):

check if the commands are exacutable:

```
ls -l adb
-rw-r--r-- 1 tsi tsi 0 Aug  5 11:58 adb
```

my user is "tsi", and I don't have e'X'ecute permissions on it, now make it executable:

```
chmod +x adb
ls -l adb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tsi tsi 0 Aug  5 11:58 adb
```

Now it should be ok.

What else could prevent to make it executable?

- the files are not on a linux filesystem
- they are on a linux filesystem, but it is mounted without execution permissions

Answer (score 0):

same problem happened for me

open the terminal and check whether adb server properly installed by the using the command

```
adb version
```

if not installed error shows then type the following command t install after that everything worked fine for me.

```
The program 'adb' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:


sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```